# Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Im building a sign up screen in flutter, and I wanted that right after creating a user, it would automatically login and redirect to home, this works but I think there may be a cleaner way to do it.

Im using firebase auth.

```
onPressed: () async {
   final userCredential = FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
     email: _emailController.text,
     password: _passwordController.text).then(
       (value) => FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
         email: _emailController.text, 
         password: _passwordController.text)).then(
           (value) => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home'));              
}
```

Comment: You can use AuthStateChange stream to automatically redirect user to home (on login) and sign in (on logout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createUserWithEmailAndPassword automatically logs the user in after creation. you don't need to do signInWithEmailAndPassword, just navigate to home page immediately.

```
onPressed: () async {
 try {
   final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
     email: _emailController.text,
     password: _passwordController.text);
    
   assert(userCredential != null);
    
   String userId = userCredential.user!.uid;

   Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home'));              
} catch (e) {
   debugPrint(e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new user account in Firebase already signs them in, so there's no need for that `signInWithEmailAndPassword` call.

---

As Vivek commented, also consider listening for the [`authStateChanges()` stream](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html), so that you can show the correct screen based on the current auth state of your app - even when the user restarts it (at which point Firebase automatically restores their authentication state).

Comment: This stream can help to protect certain screens like the [login required decorator in django?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)